# The best method to update every row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have code like this to create random table: (http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server/Creating_a_Large_Table_with_Random_Data_for_Indexes.html)

```
-- Create a table with primary key
CREATE TABLE fyi_random 
(
    id INT,
    rand_integer INT,
    rand_number numeric(18,9),
    rand_datetime DATETIME,
    rand_string VARCHAR(80)
);

-- Insert rows with random values
DECLARE @row INT;
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(80), @length INT, @code INT;
SET @row = 0;

WHILE @row < 100000 
BEGIN
    SET @row = @row + 1;

    -- Build the random string
    SET @length = ROUND(80*RAND(),0);
    SET @string = '';

    WHILE @length > 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @length = @length - 1;
        SET @code = ROUND(32*RAND(),0) - 6;

        IF @code BETWEEN 1 AND 26 
           SET @string = @string + CHAR(ASCII('a')+@code-1);
        ELSE
           SET @string = @string + ' ';
    END 

    -- Ready for the record
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO fyi_random 
    VALUES (@row, 
            ROUND(2000000*RAND()-1000000,0),
            ROUND(2000000*RAND()-1000000,9),
            CONVERT(DATETIME, ROUND(60000*RAND() - 30000, 9) ),
            @string)
END

PRINT 'Rows inserted: '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@row);
GO
```

I want to update every row (for example update column rand_string with some new random string). What is the best method? When I'm trying to do this by while loop performance decreases with increasing rows:

```
...
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE random_data 
SET rand_string = @string 
WHERE id = @row;
```

I also tried to use cursor statement and it's better but why while loop is so slow? And is there another way to do this better?

Comment: what about just use `newid()` as `UPDATE random_data SET rand_string =  newid()`;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update every row in a table then just omit the where clause in the update statement.

Comment: I think OP wants to update *specific* row, that's why `where` clause. Thus, it can't be omitted.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Maybe, but the question states twice that the OP wants to *update every row*.

Comment: When I ommit where clause it's even slower and it updates column random_string with the same one random string in every row. I want to update every row, column rand_string with new random unique string

Comment: (Executing a single statement will not be slower than executing lots of statements in a loop.) However, my answer is no longer directly relevant as your question has changed.

Comment: Ok, but why when I'm updating in while loop 10000 rows it tooks 53 second  and 100000 rows takes more than 1 hour?